# Magento 2 | Variable with StoreViewCode

Tags: magento2, frontend, store-view, variables

I want to get the BaseURL with the StoreViewCode via Magento 2 Variables but with no success. I have the "add Storeview to URL" enabled at the Backend and using the following variable only shows the Base URL without it.

```
{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}
```

Is there a variable to get the StoreviewCode as well?

Comment: where do you want to get url with store view code ? in cms page / blocks ?

Comment: exactly on CMS pages via Blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following variable to get url with store code :

`{{store direct_url=""}}`

Also this will work :

`{{store url=''}}`

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class YourClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }

    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

**Get store information in .phtml file**

```
echo $block->getStoreId();
echo $block->getStoreCode();
echo $block->getWebsiteId();
echo $block->getStoreName();
echo $block->getStoreUrl();
echo $block->isStoreActive();
```

In CMS

```
<a href="{{store url=''}}">text</a>
```

Comment: Thank your, but i want to use it with the standard Magento 2 Blocks so i cant use php function or am i wrong ?